# Upload compressed files with s3cmd guessing mime-types correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I've a large number of compressed small files (~10k, that have {txt,html,log,xml,binary}.gz extension) to be sync-ed/put into S3 buckets regularly, created with public https read access with the s3cmd. These are mostly files with different mime-types in the large directory structure.

Here are the loop returns the mime-types from the subfolder:

```
for i in $(find .); do file -ib $i ; done | sort | uniq
inode/directory; charset=binary
inode/x-empty; charset=binary
text/html; charset=utf-8
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
text/xml; charset=us-ascii
text/xml; charset=utf-8
application/x-rpm; charset=binary
```

They files are gziped and stored as `path/to/file/$name.{txt,html,log,xml,binary}.gz`

Using the below s3cmd with options `-M` and `--default-mime-type` really does not help much since all the files mime-types get set as `application/x-gzip` because of the extension.

```
s3cmd put --recursive dir -M --default-mime-type "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" --acl-public --add-header="Cache-Control:public,max-age=15552000" s3://my-test-bucket/
```

I'm trying to avoid iterating the set of files with bash for loop, to retrieve each file the mime-types and push files one at a time, which would be very slow as compared to doing a recursive put/sync. Is there an option or a way to handle this correctly?

Is it possible to enable compression at the bucket level so that files are compressed and uploaded on the fly with s3cmd without needing them to gzip? If this is available this would definitely help with keeping the upload bandwidth lower before the total of compressed files is about ~10Mib, as compared to the uncompressed file which is about close to ~1Gib. Adding "content-encoding: gzip" would still require gzipping the files?